# Will my app get approved by the App Store if it has too many String data type?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am creating this song lyrics app. It should have about 500 songs in it. I want to put all the song lyrics as String within Switch/if statements without using API because I want the user to be able to access the lyrics offline.

Comment: No issue. But "Switch/if", I hope it can be simplified and that's can be optimized in a coding way.

Comment: Use a local data store, like a SQLite database, or even just a YAML, JSON, CSV, etc. file.

Comment: Thank you both for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get rejected for using too many String or switch/if statements. The App Store does not review your code quality.

However, you might get rejected on copyright grounds if you are unable to show that you have permission from the copyright holders to reproduce their work.

> 5.2 Intellectual Property
>
> Make sure your app only includes content that you created or that you
>   have a license to use. Your app may be removed if you’ve stepped over
>   the line and used content without permission.